# Deny response from API Gateway when IP address is not whitelisted

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

**Context**

I'm using a resource policy to whitelist IP addresses which can call my APIs managed using API Gateway.

My resource policy looks like this

[image: Resource policy on API Gateway]

When I try to call the API from a IP address thats not in the whitelist, I get an API response like this -

```
{
    "Message": "User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:ap-sou*******-*:************:*****/*****/**/******"
}
```

**Problem**

I would prefer to not show an error message at all when the IP address is not in the whitelist.

**Expected Outcome**

How can I change the response to only display error messages to IP addresses that are whitelisted? For IP addresses that are not in the whitelist, there should be no response. Similar to what EC2 instances do when the IP address is not whitelisted and the operation times out.

**EDIT**: There is another question with a similar problem - [AWS API Gateway change access denied response message from resource policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60746261/aws-api-gateway-change-access-denied-response-message-from-resource-policy)

But my problem is different because I don't just want to change the response sent, but I would like to stop API Gateway from sending a response if the IP address is not whitelisted.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60746261/aws-api-gateway-change-access-denied-response-message-from-resource-policy/60761843#60761843

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS API Gateway change access denied response message from resource policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60746261/aws-api-gateway-change-access-denied-response-message-from-resource-policy)

Comment: Thanks for this link. I checked it out, but the problem is slightly different. I don't just want to change the response message but I want to stop API Gateway from returning a response altogether. Not sure if API Gateway can do that.

Comment: what do you want API GW to do, just hang?  This is not efficient as it will leave tcp connections open.  You should be able to configure the response to just be something like `{}` which is essentially no response

Comment: Thanks for that @JDD That might be my solution if I cant find a way to not return a response. I'm expecting a behaviour similar to what EC2 instances do when the IP address is not whitelisted in the security group. There is no response sent and eventually the operation times out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As folks in the comments have suggestion, you could consider using [Gateway Response](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-gatewayResponse-definition.html) to simplify the response to essentially nothing by having it return something like `{}`.

Another approach to consider if you want similar responses from EC2 instances would be to *not* use API Gateway and use an [Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html) to act as your proxy.  I am not sure what type of integration you are using with API Gateway but ALBs allow you to [route traffic to Lambdas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/lambda-functions.html), [route traffic to EC2 instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-register-targets.html) or [forward/redirect traffic to other HTTP endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-rules.html) so this solution would work for those types of integrations.  You can then setup the security groups on the ALB to only allow traffic from white listed subnets and any other users that attempt to make requests will simply hang.