# Provide custom message in resource policy of AWS API GATEWAY

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I have implemented AWS API Gateway Resource Policy like below --

```
{
    "Version": "v1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "1.2.3.4"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am getting the below message which is fine as I am calling from different IP --

> {"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform:
> execute-api:Invoke on resource:
> arn:aws:execute-api:ap-south-1:********9123:mp6512bw/dev/GET/api/url
> with an explicit deny"}

I just want to know is there any way to provide custom message ?

Comment: @Nick thanks buddy . This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60761843/3967525 helps . Actually I have tried earlier but forgot to re-deploy .